# equi join using awk in bash script

Tags: bash, awk

I have 3 files. file1 is having movies data (movies id and movies type like hoorror , romance and comedy). file2 is having users data (user id, gender, occupation). file3 is having Rating data (user id, movie id and rating).

Now, i need to find the movie type liked by females(rating > 3 is considered as most liked) using awk in bash script.

Comment: You need to provide samples from each of the files and then show us what code you have tried so far.

Comment: Also, you need to look for duplicates.  How to join stuff in Awk is a very frequently asked question on https://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

I realise I may get punished for not really answering the question, but what you're asking can be done easily with [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/).

The following session illustrates querying the data to return movies where the average rating by females is `>= 3`:

```
$ sqlite3 
SQLite version 3.8.2 2013-12-06 14:53:30
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .separator ,
sqlite> .import movie_data.csv  movie
sqlite> .import user_data.csv user
sqlite> .import rating_data.csv rating
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE movie(
  "movie_id" TEXT,
  "movie_type" TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE user(
  "user_id" TEXT,
  "gender" TEXT,
  "occupation" TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE rating(
  "user_id" TEXT,
  "movie_id" TEXT,
  "rating" TEXT
);
sqlite> select r.movie_id, avg(r.rating) from rating r
   ...> inner join user u on r.user_id = u.user_id
   ...> where u.gender = 'F'
   ...> group by r.movie_id
   ...> having avg(r.rating) >= 3;
1,10.0
2,4.5
4,6.5
sqlite>
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer because that's exactly my idea: don't rewrite a database system in `awk` if you can use one...

Answer (score 0):

First, we want a list of females ids

```
females=$(awk '$2=="female"{printf $1 ","}' victims.txt)
```

Next, we want a list of movie ids liked by females,
we pass the list of females to the awk command, and first of all we put all the female ids in an array variable by splitting the females *CSV* string and placing it into an array

```
movies=$(awk -v females="$females" '
   BEGIN{split(females,temp,",");
         for(i in temp) flist[temp[i]]}
   $3>3 {if($1 in flist) printf $2 ","}' ratings.txt)
```

at this point, we're ready to scan the movies file, as before we want to unpack the data prepared in the previous step (this time, counting the occurrences), then it's just as simple as printing the movie genre as many times as it was rated favourably, sorting and using the `uniq` utility.

```
awk -v movies="$movies" '
   BEGIN{split(movies,temp,",");
         for(i in temp) mlist[temp[i]]++}
   {if($1 in mlist) for(i=0;i<mlist[$1];i++)print $2}' movies.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

#### Disclaimer

As I have no data whatsoever, the amount of testing that was possible was near to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Using `join`, assuming that `people.csv` and `movies.csv` are already sorted on the primary key, assuming that genre is either `f` or `m`

```
sort -n -t, ratings.csv | join -t, people.csv - | sort -n -t, -k4,4 | join -t, -2 4 movies.csv - | awk -F, '$4=="f"&&$6>3'
```

will happily print a list with the following fields

```
movie_id, movie_genre, id, genre, occupation, movie_rating
```

that you can further filter using awk and postprocess using sort and uniq as we have seen previously.

I needed to understand how `join` works...

It's worth mentioning that, using `bash`, one can use *process substitution* (the `<(...)` construct) to write a pipeless command line, but `join` supports reading from stdin and the pipeline solution is more general.

Comment: If my assumption that `people.csv` and `movies.csv` are already sorted on the primary key were false, the pipeline only solution won't work and one has to use temporary files or, if s/he has `bash`, the _process substitution_ mechanism.